# Records are getting saved even after validation fails in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have a model Taluka where we are supposed to select district and enter as many talukas.

But the issue is that records are getting saved even if some talukas are empty.
Here is my code:

```
public function actionCreate()
    {

      $model = new Taluka();

      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

                $talukaslist = $model->talukas;

                if(is_array($talukaslist))
                {

                    foreach($talukaslist as $taluka)
                     {
                         if($taluka == null)
                         {
                                  return $this->render('create', [
                                    'model' => $model,
                                  ]);
                         }
                         else
                          if($taluka!=null)
                          {
                           $talukaRecord = new Taluka();
                           $talukaRecord->DistrictId = $model->DistrictId;
                           $talukaRecord->Taluka = $taluka;
                           $talukaRecord->save(false);
                          }
                     }
                }

                 return $this->redirect(['index']);

      }  
         else {
            return $this->render('create', [
               'model' => $model,


            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you print $talukaslist value

Comment: Also $talukaRecord->save(false); false means that it will skip the validations. Remove false and then check

Comment: You have switched validation off - save(**false**) - and you expect it to work...

Comment: When I remove false, it doesnt gets save. But now when the all talukas are entered, still the records are not getting saved

Comment: Check which attribute is problem, by removing it from required one by one. Use save without false.