# Records are not getting saved in database table in yii2

Tags: yii2, yii2-basic-app

I have taluka model where we select district and enter as many talukas.
But the records are not getting saved.

```
public function actionCreate()
    {

      $model = new Taluka();

      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

                $talukaslist = $model->talukas;

                if(is_array($talukaslist))
                {

                    foreach($talukaslist as $taluka)
                     {
                         if($taluka ==null)
                         {
                                  return $this->render('create', [
                                    'model' => $model,
                                  ]);
                         }
                         else
                        if($taluka!=null)
                         {
                         $talukaRecord = new Taluka();
                         $talukaRecord->DistrictId = $model->DistrictId;
                         $talukaRecord->Taluka = $taluka;
                         $talukaRecord->save();
                         }
                     }
                }

                 return $this->redirect(['index']);  
      }  

         else {
            return $this->render('create', [
               'model' => $model,


            ]);
        }
    }
```

If I use $talukaRecord->save(false), then the records are getting saved even if the validation fails.

Model:

```
<?php

namespace app\models;

use Yii;

/**
 * This is the model class for table "taluka".
 *
 * @property integer $TalukaId
 * @property integer $DistrictId
 * @property string $Taluka
 *
 * @property Area[] $areas
 * @property Colony[] $colonies
 * @property Colonydemographic[] $colonydemographics
 * @property District $district
 * @property Village[] $villages
 * @property Villagedemographic[] $villagedemographics
 */
class Taluka extends \yii\db\ActiveRecord
{
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */


    public $talukas=[];

    public static function tableName()
    {
        return 'taluka';
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['DistrictId', 'Taluka'], 'required'],
            [['DistrictId'], 'integer'],
            [['talukas'], 'required'],
            [['Taluka'], 'string', 'max' => 100],
            [['DistrictId'], 'exist', 'skipOnError' => true, 'targetClass' => District::className(), 'targetAttribute' => ['DistrictId' => 'DistrictId']],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
        return [
            'TalukaId' => 'Taluka ID',
            'DistrictId' => 'District',
            'talukas' => 'Taluka',
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getAreas()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Area::className(), ['TalukaId' => 'TalukaId']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getColonies()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Colony::className(), ['TalukaId' => 'TalukaId']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getColonydemographics()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Colonydemographic::className(), ['TalukaId' => 'TalukaId']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getDistrict()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(District::className(), ['DistrictId' => 'DistrictId']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getVillages()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Village::className(), ['TalukaId' => 'TalukaId']);
    }

    /**
     * @return \yii\db\ActiveQuery
     */
    public function getVillagedemographics()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Villagedemographic::className(), ['TalukaId' => 'TalukaId']);
    }
}
```

Comment: Then, it is working as expected, right? Check why you model fails validation

Comment: try `print_r($talukaRecord->getErrors())`, to check what validations rules are failing.

Comment: Update your question with model **Taluka.php** file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Records are getting saved even after validation fails in yii2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43782253/records-are-getting-saved-even-after-validation-fails-in-yii2)

Comment: I entered two talukas for selected district and it shows foll                    
Array ( [talukas] => Array ( [0] => Taluka cannot be blank. ) ) Array ( [talukas] => Array ( [0] => Taluka cannot be blank. ) )

Answer (score 0):

Please try below code

```
public function actionCreate()
    {

      $model = new Taluka();

      if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) ) {

                $talukaslist = $model->talukas;

                if(isset($talukaslist) && && $talukaslist!=array())
                {

                    foreach($talukaslist as $taluka)
                     {
                         if(isset($taluka) && $taluka ==null)
                         {
                                  return $this->render('create', [
                                    'model' => $model,
                                  ]);
                         }
                         else
                        if(isset($taluka) && $taluka!=null)
                         {
                            $talukaRecord = new Taluka();
                            $talukaRecord->DistrictId = $model->DistrictId;
                            $talukaRecord->Taluka = $taluka;
                            if($talukaRecord->save())
                            {}
                            else
                            {
                               echo "<pre>";
                               print_r($talukaRecord->getErrors());die;
                            }

                         }
                     }
                }

                 return $this->redirect(['index']);  
      }  

         else {
            return $this->render('create', [
               'model' => $model,


            ]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Code is not working, even if all values are entered, still error is shown as Array
(
    [talukas] => Array
        (
            [0] => Talukas cannot be blank.
        )

)